# How to get key and values using NamedTuple

Tags: python-3.x, namedtuple, python-dataclasses

Python 3.9.6

I have been trying to figure out on how I am able to print the key and value when I have given variable that I want to specific get from a NamedTuple.

I have created my own NamedTuple that I import via configuration that reads TOML file which can be read below:

```
from config import configuration

"""
[discord]
    [discord.filtered]
        [[discord.filtered.swedish]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/1...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/2...."
            
        [[discord.unfiltered.mixed]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/7...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/8..."   
            
    [discord.unfiltered]
        [[discord.unfiltered.swedish]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/3...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/4...."
         
        [[discord.unfiltered.mixed]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/6..."   
"""
filtered = True  # Or False
type_filter = "swedish"  # Or mixed

collection = configuration.discord.filtered if filtered else configuration.discord.unfiltered
```

I was able to figure out if filtered is true then we go into the filtered path in the configuration else unfiltered, but then my problem starts here. I do not know how I can print out the region and the URL if I want to use swedish or mixed.

The output I want to get is that e.g.

```
filtered = True  # Or False
type_filter = "swedish"  # Or mixed
```

> should print out

```
eu,  https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/1....
asia, https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/2....
```

where eu/asia is one variable and the URL its own variable

How am I able to print the region and the url based on filtered and type_filter?

Update after Enzo answer:

```
filtered = True  # Or False
type_filter = "swedish"  # Or mixed

collection = configuration.discord.filtered if filtered else configuration.discord.unfiltered

for regions in getattr(collection, type_filter):
    for region, discord_collection in regions.items():
        print(f"Region: {region}, URL {discord_collection}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`toml` library](https://github.com/uiri/toml#installation):

```
data = """
[discord]
    [discord.filtered]
        [[discord.filtered.swedish]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/1...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/2...."
            
        [[discord.unfiltered.mixed]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/7...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/8..."   
            
    [discord.unfiltered]
        [[discord.unfiltered.swedish]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/3...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/4...."
         
        [[discord.unfiltered.mixed]]
            eu = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5...."
            asia = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/6..."   
"""

import toml

mapping = toml.loads(data)
print(mapping)
```

Outputs

```
{'discord': {'discord.filtered': {'discord.filtered.swedish': {'asia': '...', 'eu': '...'},
                                  'discord.unfiltered.mixed': {'asia': '...', 'eu': '...'}},
             'discord.unfiltered': {'discord.unfiltered.mixed': {'asia': '...', 'eu': '...'},
                                    'discord.unfiltered.swedish': {'asia': '...', 'eu': '...'}}}}
```

Then, just create a function to filter the resulting dictionary:

```py
def filter_dict(dicts, name: str, filtered: bool):
    key_1st = "discord"
    key_2nd = "filtered" if filtered else "unfiltered"
    key_3rd = name
    return dicts[key_1st]['.'.join((key_1st, key_2nd))]['.'.join((key_1st, key_2nd, key_3rd))] 

print(filter_dict(mapping, name="swedish", filtered=True))
# Outputs {'eu': 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/1....', 'asia': 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/2....'}
```

Comment: Hi Enzo!

I managed to do something like this but im not sure what you think - I will update my question to see if that is something is good to do?